# Error logging associative array properties that are functions using `util.inspect` in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, associative-array

I'm using node.js's `util.inspect` call to dump a JavaScript associative array to the log. The associative array in question includes member properties that are functions. An example is:

```
var pendingscreen = {};
pendingscreen['timeoutfunction'] = function(){ sendmsg(); };
pendingscreen['timeout'] = setTimeout(pendingscreen['timeoutfunction'], 1000);
console.log(util.inspect(pendingscreen));
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Function.prototype.toString is not generic
    at Client.toString (native)
    at String.STRING_ADD_LEFT (native)
    at isRegExp (util.js:287:14)
    at format (util.js:184:11)
    at util.js:216:19
    at Array.map (native)
    at format (util.js:193:23)
    at util.js:216:19
    at Array.map (native)
    at format (util.js:193:23)
```

Is there any way to inspect the members of an associative array where some of the members could be functions?

Comment: Can you confirm for me that this isn't a problem caused by something in your sendmsg() function? Just do "pendingscreen['timeoutfunction'] = function(){};".

Comment: Its not: I changed it to an anonymous function earlier and it still blows up. I gave up and just restructured my code so I don't need to use `util.inspect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`util.inspect` should handle this just fine. However there is a [bug in the node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/0c91a835ff7d5fd1ee288d11d977a95122aa400e) version you are using which can cause this error.

This is fixed in newer version (>=0.4.11).

Answer (score 0):

That actually looks like a bug in Node to me.

Normally it would just print out "[Function]" when you inspect the object.

Edit: I'm not sure this is actually the issue anymore. 
This error is triggered by something like this:

```
(function(){ }).toString.call(null)
```

Calling the Function 'toString' with something that is not a function. I have no idea how that would happen though.

Comment: Interesting: 0.4.11 is what is reported.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I just tried pasting your sample code into a node 0.4.11 terminal and it worked fine.

Still try giving a new version a shot though.